# Как тестировать API через PHPUnit

Tags: php, api, phpunit

Имеется API, которое возвращает JSON ответ

```
{
    "debug": [
        {
             "https://website.net/api/v1/get/pages/list/ -> total": 0.03785991668701172
        }
    ],
    "error": "Required option site not exist",
    "result": null,
    "post_action": null,
    "version": "0437d1531c3e5238dda3f6b96392695c"
}
```

Как мне протестировать используя PHPUnit, что, допустим, ответ будет содержать **именно 5 значений**(debug,error,result,post_action,version)

И что error, к примеру будет **Required option site not exist"**

Я пробовал делать запрос через Guzzle, потом сверять ответ. Как лучше это вообще делать? Через file_get_contents или curl или Guzzle или ещё что-то?

Comment: PHPUnit для unit тестирования, у вас интеграционное, возьмите соответствующий интрумент

Comment: Что Вы имеете ввиду? Например какой инструмент?

Comment: Guzzle, file_get_contents, curl, создавать объект запроса и "скармливать" приложению (если сделано приложение соответсвующим образом), я к тому что не надо привязываться к phpUnit

Comment: Думаю, что для общего развития можно посмотреть [исходники тестов](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/tree/master/tests/ReCaptcha) для Google reCaptcha.